# How to test @mui/x-date-pickers with @react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, react-testing-library

I try to write a test for my Form with a DatePicker component. I am using @mui/x-date-pickers in the latest version 6.2.0.

When I run the test below I get the message:

"TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of: 15"

The question is, how do I select a certain date within my test form.

Any help is appreciated.

```ts
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    render,
    fireEvent,
    screen
} from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";


import {DatePicker} from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker'; // version 6.2.0
import {  LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';


test("renders DatePicker", async () => {
    const handleChange = jest.fn();
    const { getByLabelText } = render(
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DatePicker
                label="Select a date"
                value={null}
                onChange={handleChange}

            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    );

    const input = getByLabelText('Select a date');
    fireEvent.focus(input); // Open the DatePicker popover
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('15')); // Click on a day in the DatePicker
    expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Date(2023, 3, 15)); // Verify that the onChange handler was called with the selected date
});
```

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it?